# Facebook SDK Without Login - App Install Tracking Only

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I just want the Facebook SDK for conversion tracking. I need the SDK to verify downloads when running Facebook "App Install" campaigns. However, I do not want my users to have to Login to Facebook when they open my app!

Can I just install part of the SDK, skip the login steps, and still get the conversion tracking? Maybe even event tracking?

I've watched several tutorials on how to install the SDK BUT they all include steps for login functionality:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8T19jBUadaM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ye3RtZ65npU

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was "yes'. In other words, I was able to get the conversion tracking function without adopting the login feature. Here's the [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#sdk).

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059797/not-receiving-data-from-facebook-ios-sdk) I outlined the steps to do it. Same steps as the guide but explained in different words / images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that explains caching that you can use for the purpose...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/token-cache