# Not Receiving Data From Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to get the Facebook SDK to work. The only goal I'm trying to achieve is to verify activations, I'm not using the login, sharing. etc. Every install step is complete but when I check the analytics it's not logging data. Does anyone have an idea as to why?

### If needed, my install process is outlined below:

1) [I downloaded the SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#sdk) yesterday. I dragged the bolts and core files into my project navigator then, in the Build Settings, I've added the path to the framework:

> "/Users/Dave/Documents/Misc/FacebookSDKs-iOS"

2) I setup my app on the [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/655465217925097/settings/) page with my App ID and Bundle ID:

[image: FB Developer Section]

3) On that same page I have single sign-on enabled:

[image: FB Single Sign-On]

4) Under "Build Phases", in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, I see the right files:

[image: Link Binary with Libraries]

5) In my info.plist file I also have all the code it requested:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>(my_FB-ID_IsHere)</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>(DisplayNameIsHere)</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
      <string>fbauth2</string>
      <string>fbshareextension</string>
  </array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

6) A picture of my info.plist after code was added:

[image: info.plist setup for Facebook SDK]

7) In the app delegate file I believe I have the correct Swift code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

//Other code...

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

8) Because I'm using Swift, I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@patrickhsanders/getting-started-guide-for-facebook-sdk-v4-8-0-with-swift-2-1-1-and-xcode-7-2-c05b1da11dad) and added a "Bridge-Header.h" file with this code:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h 

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

So that's it... right? Where's my data!? This is all I see:

[image: Test App Events]

[image: FB SDK Quick Start Prompt]

[image: No FB SDK Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that their was a small error in my info.plist:

I had added the "FB" prefix to my app ID (for example: "FB1234567"). This is necessary for the top ID but not the bottom:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb1234567</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1234567</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>MyAppName</string>
```